# How does the term "characteristic" differ from ODE to PDE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Whenever I hear characteristic equations in ODE, I see some exponential test function.

Whenever I hear characteristic equations in PDE, I see parameterizations.

Are these different concepts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, characteristic polynomials and characteristic curves are quite different concepts. Sometimes you have to take a word literally, "something that characterizes something else, extracts some trait of it".

Note that the characteristic *curves* of 1st order PDE are solutions of the Lagrange *equations*.

Comment: I was hoping you'd expand more on what they actually are in PDE, but I guess that's good enough.

Comment: They are curves along which the PDE can be reduced to an ODE, the wikipedia article is quite good on the motivation for this.